# Python Tkinter Click event and Right Click

Tags: python, tkinter, events

I want the user to be able to right click and chose and option, and also be able to double click on the item.

Right now I have a right click menu that is available to the user. They can right click on the line of the treeview they want, and it opens up a new window for them to update/change the information.

```
self.rc_menu_contree = Menu(self.condition_tree, tearoff=False)
self.rc_menu_contree.add_command(label="New Condition", command=self.add_new_condition_window)
self.rc_menu_contree.add_command(label="Update Condition", command=self.update_condition_window)
self.rc_menu_contree.add_command(label="Duplicate Condition", command=self.copy_condition)
self.rc_menu_contree.add_separator()
self.rc_menu_contree.add_command(label="Delete Condition", command=self.delete_condition)
```

So when they want to update the condition in the tree, they can right click and select that option.

However, what I would like to do is also give them the option to double click on the treeview item.

```
self.condition_tree.bind("<Double--1>", self.update_condition_window)
```

The only way I can get this to work, is if I duplicate the method with an event argument. But that method is quite long. I was hoping there is a way to pass in a dummy event argument in the right click menu using lambda? i.e.

```
self.rc_menu_contree.add_command(label="Update Condition", command=lamda: self.update_condition_window(dummy event))
```

tried putting fake event in.

Comment: just make the argument kwarg i.e. `def update_condition_window(event=None): ...`

Comment: I knew there was a simple answer, thank you so much!

Comment: Also, the event is `<Double-1>`, not `<Double--1>`.

Comment: That is interesting. Mine doesn't work unless I have the 2 dashes.